# Adding am UIPageViewController in front of a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

When my app starts for the first time it should display a tutorial, which are some screens with a semitransparent background, in front of the first app screen.

I tried creating an UIPageViewController object, adding its view as subview of the current screen (`self.view.addSubview(tutorialViewController.view)`) and the screen is displayed, however when I swipe the `UIPageViewController` is not responding the event.

```
class TutorialViewController:UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
var tutorialsViewControllers = [UIViewController]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tutorialsViewControllers.append(Tutorial1ViewController())
    tutorialsViewControllers.append(Tutorial2ViewController())
    tutorialsViewControllers.append(Tutorial3ViewController())
    tutorialsViewControllers.append(Tutorial4ViewController())
    tutorialsViewControllers.append(Tutorial5ViewController())
    self.setViewControllers([tutorialsViewControllers.first!], direction: .Forward, animated: false) { (complete) -> Void in
    }
    self.dataSource = self
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let position = find(self.tutorialsViewControllers, viewController)
        where position > 0
    {
        return self.tutorialsViewControllers[position - 1]
    }
    return nil
}
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    if let position = find(self.tutorialsViewControllers, viewController)
        where position < self.tutorialsViewControllers.count - 1
    {
        return self.tutorialsViewControllers[position - 1]
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

That's the view controller code

```
let tutorialViewController = TutorialViewController()        
self.view.addSubview(tutorialViewController.view)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the `tutorialViewController` as child view controller?

```
self.addChildViewController(tutorialViewController)
self.view.addSubview(tutorialViewController.view)
```